# Is collaring a circuit breaker considered deactivation by the FAA?

Tags: faa-regulations, preflight, circuit-breaker

Let's say you discover that your landing light is inoperable during the preflight. Your aircraft doesn't have a MEL, so you follow 14 CFR §91.213(d). Assuming you do everything else required (placard, etc.), would placing a collar around a circuit breaker be considered deactivation?

If not, is there anything that a private pilot can do that would be considered deactivation?

Comment: The humorous absurdity of pulling & collaring a breaker (interrupting the circuit) for a failed landing light (usually because the incandescent filament has burned out, *interrupting the circuit*) is not lost on me. Though on a serious note, if we're talking about a fault in a [HID landing light system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-intensity_discharge_lamp) or [LED landing light](http://www.whelen.com/pb/Aviation/Product%20Sheets/Parmetheus_Series.pdf) the potential failure modes certainly warrant "preventing the operation" of the system until you know what caused the fault...

Comment: It does seem a bit absurd. I asked this question because it's one that seems to come up in checkrides. During my checkride I was asked what I would do in this situation. I answered that I would collar the circuit breaker, and the DE told me that would not be enough and I would have to have a certified mechanic repair the light or disconnect the power to the circuit breaker to be legal. I didn't argue, but I'm pretty sure he's wrong and the collaring is deactivation.

Comment: I would think collaring qualifies as deactivation too - certainly as lnafziger pointed out it's what manufacturers recommend, and I'm pretty sure it's what airlines do for non-critical equipment that needs to be "tagged out" because it's broken. For that matter taping a bent index card cover over the switch so you can't turn it on it would also seem to qualify, albeit a somewhat inelegant solution.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Based on [this Advisory Circular](http://rgl.faa.gov/Regulatory_and_Guidance_Library/rgAdvisoryCircular.nsf/0/13c094a06437c5fa862569d900744d86/%24FILE/Chap1-2.pdf), the answer is yes.

> g. Deactivation means to make a piece of equipment or an instrument unusable to the pilot/crew by preventing its operation

Collaring the circuit breaker prevents it from being pushed in, and therefore prevents its operation.

Comment: This is consistent with MEL M&O procedures that in some cases specify doing exactly this.